# Error while training a neural network in opencv

Tags: c, ubuntu, opencv, neural-network

I have been working on this for quite some time now but I am not able to figure out the problem here.I am working on Ubuntu in Opencv using eclipse.
I am trying to train the neural network with some values.A few sample values are 
62  63  45  0.175925925925926   0.285714285714286 0.247058823529412 1
49  51  37  0.190476190476190   0.274509803921569 0.200000000000000 1

Here is the entire loop of the neural network training.
 FILE* fid= fopen("treewall","r");

```
            while (fscanf(fid,"%f",&a)==1)
            {
                    printf("%f\n",a);
                    trainsamplecount=trainsamplecount+1;
            }
            cout<<trainsamplecount<<endl;
            rewind(fid);
            float td[2000][7];
            int numoftestpoints;
            CvMat* traindata=cvCreateMat(trainsamplecount,6,CV_32FC1);
            CvMat* trainclasses=cvCreateMat(trainsamplecount,1,CV_32FC1);
            CvMat* samplewts=cvCreateMat(trainsamplecount,1,CV_32FC1);
            CvMat* neurallayers=cvCreateMat(4,1,CV_32SC1);
            CvMat traindata1,trainclasses1,neurallayers1,samplewts1;


            cvGetRows(neurallayers,&neurallayers1,0,4);

            cvSet1D(&neurallayers1, 0, cvScalar(6));
            cvSet1D(&neurallayers1,1,cvScalar(3));
            cvSet1D(&neurallayers1,2,cvScalar(3));
            cvSet1D(&neurallayers1, 3, cvScalar(1));

         // CvMat* outdata=Mat::ones(trainsamplecount/7,1,CV_8U);
         // CvMat* testdata(numoftestpoints,7,CV_32FC1);
            cout<<traindata->rows<<endl;
            cout<<traindata->cols<<endl;
            int i=0,j=0;

            if(fid)
            {
            for(int i=0;i<trainsamplecount;i++)
                fscanf(fid,"%f %f %f %f %f %f %f ",&td[i][0],&td[i][1],&td[i][2],&td[i][3],&td[i][4],&td[i][5],&td[i][6]);


            for (i=0;i<trainsamplecount;i++)
            {
                cout<<i<<endl;
                cvGetRow(traindata,&traindata1,i);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,0,(float)td[i][0]);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,1,(float)td[i][1]);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,2,(float)td[i][2]);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,3,(float)td[i][3]);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,4,(float)td[i][4]);
                cvSetReal2D(&traindata1,i,5,(float)td[i][5]);
                cvGetRow(trainclasses,&trainclasses1,i);
                cvSet1D(&trainclasses1,i,cvRealScalar(1));
                cvGetRow(samplewts,&samplewts1,i);


                cvSet1D(samplewts,i,cvRealScalar(1));

            }
            }
```

But this loop terminates at the statement cvGetRow(trainclasses,&trainclasses1,i);
Before it used to dispaly a bad argument error at the line cvSet1D(samplewts,i,cvRealScalar(1));

Please help me solve this issue as I am not able to think of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line

```
cvSet1D(&trainclasses1,i,cvRealScalar(1));
```

should be

```
cvSet1D(&trainclasses1,0,cvRealScalar(1));
```

, since trainclasses1 will have 1 row and 1 column.